# How to execute multiple pytest suites (files) parallelly at a time

Tags: python, testing, pytest, parallel-execution

I am trying to execute multiple pytest suites at a time i.e parallel execution but I couldn't find the solution, can someone please help me with this.

For example, I've two test suites

```
1. test_one.py
2. test_two.py
```

If I use the following command the execution will be sequential i.e one after another. But I would like to execute the two test suites parallelly at the same time

`pytest test_one.py test_two.py -vvs`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins for pytest: [xdist](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist) or [pytest-parallel](https://github.com/browsertron/pytest-parallel)